# Initialize all Flutter class instances with same ID and no need to provide argument

Tags: flutter, class, dart

I am working on a flutter app and wanted one of my classes to have the same `id` property. This is because I can have either an event or an exception, but I would like the same function to manage both. To do this, I have a switch statement that checks `res.id` to determine which type of event it is. The response can either be an `Event` instance or an `Exception` instance.

`Exception` is an import class and I'd rather not have to wrap it in an `Event` instance so I thought I could just hardcode `id = EventIds.error`. This way every error will have an id that matches an error event - thus it can be accessed and dealt with in the original switch statement.

My issue is I don't want to have to go all throughout my code and add a new argument to each instantiation. See the code below.

**Exception.dart**

```
class Exception {
  /// Always initialize with id that is error id
  /// This is for onCaptureEvent  
  int id = EventIds.error;
  int code = 0;
  String message = 'no error';
  String? method;
  String? details;

  Exception(id, this.code, this.message, [this.method, this.details]);
}
```

**Instantiation Current**

```
Exception ex = new Exception(-93, 'Unable to validate')
```

I want to be able to have every instance of `Exception` have an id of `EventIds.error` *WITHOUT* having to go through every instantiation in my code and add it like so:

```
Exception ex = new Exception(EventIds.error, -93, 'Unable to validate')
```

Is this achievable in Flutter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was really simple. I just needed to write out my Exception class like so:

**Exception.dart**

```
class Exception {
  /// Always initialize with id that is error id
  /// This is for onCaptureEvent  
  int id = EventIds.error;
  int code = 0;
  String message = 'no error';
  String? method;
  String? details;

  Exception(this.code, this.message, [this.method, this.details]);
}
```

This way the instances will always use the default value for `id`. This is also safer bc now the user cannot change the ID if they wanted to provide another argument (`Exception(supplied_id, code, message)`) because it will throw a syntax error saying the second argument is supposed to be a string.